# How to overlay only the needed image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have two images.

Image 1:

[image]

Image 2:

[image]

Both the images have the same resolution. I want to overlay the second image on the first image.

This is what I tried:

```
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open("D:\\obj1__0.png")
img1 = img1.convert("RGBA")
img1 = img1.resize((640,360))

img2 = Image.open('D:\\Renderforest_Watermark.png')
img2 = img2.convert("RGBA")
img2 = img2.resize((640,360))

new_img = Image.blend(img1,img2,0.7)
new_img.save("D:\\Final.png")
```

Output:

[image]

**My Question:** How do I overlay image 2 on image 1 such that only the watermark is overlaid?

P.S: I already searched for this on Stack Overflow, but couldn't find any answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PIL : PNG image as watermark for a JPG image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43708681/pil-png-image-as-watermark-for-a-jpg-image)

Comment: @RandomDavis Nope. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Can you clarify what didn't work about it? Does your overlay image not have transparency? Did you try making the background transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overlay image is incorrectly formed. It should be transparent where it is white. It has no transparency, so it isn't see-through. I can only suggest to make a synthetic alpha channel by guessing that it should be transparent where the overlay image is white:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Set a common size
size = (640, 360)

# Load background and overlay, removing the pointless alpha channel and resizing to a common size
bg = Image.open('background.png').convert('RGB').resize(size)
overlay = Image.open('overlay.png').convert('RGB').resize(size)

# Try and invent a mask by making white pixels transparent
mask = overlay.convert('L')
mask = mask.point(lambda p: 255 if p < 225 else 0)

# Paste overlay onto background only where the mask is, then save
bg.paste(overlay, None, mask)
bg.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

If your image did have an alpha channel, you would avoid deleting the original alpha channel and open it like this instead:

```
overlay = Image.open('overlay.png').resize(size)
```

then delete these lines:

```
# Try and invent a mask by making white pixels transparent
mask = overlay.convert('L')
mask = mask.point(lambda p: 255 if p < 225 else 0)
```

then change the line after the above to:

```
# Paste overlay onto background only where the mask is, then save
bg.paste(overlay, None, overlay)
```

---

**Keywords**: Image processing, PIL, Pillow, overlay, watermark, transparent, alpha.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Could you pls explain in detail what do these two lines do:

```mask = overlay.convert('L')
mask = mask.point(lambda p: 255 if p < 225 else 0)```